# ExtJs (6.0.0) rest service PUT request

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I am trying to PUT some data from my frontend (ExtJs) into my backend (Java, Spring). It does not work or I do not get the right clue...

I am on a **Ext.grid.Panel** where I use the following store which is (nicely) filled and displayed by a **this.store.setData( myObject.data.items )** method:

```
Ext.define( 'NameOfThisClass', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  ...

  store: Ext.create( 'Ext.data.Store', {
    data: [],
    autoLoad: false,

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/somepath/theclass',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        },
    }
  } ),

  ...
  // setting the data to be visualized
  setValue: function(myObject) {
    this.store.setData( myObject.data.items );
  }
  ...

  updateRecord: function(objectId, objectWithUpdateProperties) {
    // do what with the store and/or proxy?
  }
  ...
});
```

I display all entries in a table. The entries are not automatically loaded by the store but set from outside: **setValue(myObject)**.
There is another store for initially loading the data. The data received is then splittet and forwarded in order not to have several requests.

I do get a nice visualized table whose entries are editable by the **rowediting** plugin.

Ok, so far the backgrounds.

When editing the table's data I run through some validations and gather more data via a modal dialog and then I have the data in order to send to the server by a call of **updateRecord(objectId, objectWithUpdateProperties)**.

This sending is my problem. I do not know how to call/send a rest/put request which will be read by the server. (Receiving is not the problem, sending is).

I guess I somewhat need to trigger my store or the store's proxy. But how?
It is not that I can simply tell my object to save since I do have more data than just the changed object's properties.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: exactly what you need ?

Answer (score 1):

I normally use Ext.Ajax to achieve that, like this:

```
updateRecord: function(objectId, objectWithUpdateProperties) {

    Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'YourUrl',
        params: {       
            some_param: 'some_value',
            object_id: objectId,
            object_with_properties_param1: objectWithUpdateProperties.param1
        },
        success: function(response, opts) {     
            //Horay, Do something with the response
        },
        failure: function(response, opts) {
            //Oh nooooo            
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. Thank you Fabio.
Since my URL reflects the entity id I call __url: 'YourUrl/'+objectId__ and parameters are simply set as __params: objectWithUpdateProperties__

Comment: Just some further info: I needed a PUT request and so I set __method:'PUT'__ as next property to __url__.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use Ajax. 
You need to config ***proxy.api*** CRUD(*C:create, R:read, U:Update. D:Delete*) on RestProxy, from client side.
Also, store must have ***autoSync:true***.

At server side, need to config a @RestController for each one of CRUD (with **JSON-Java encoder** for parameters like **Jackson** or equivalent), that will acept JSON data. Take into account, that you may send only modified field (***store.proxy.writer.writeAllFields: false*** ->>> ***default***) or just the full record (***.writeAllFields:true***) to server.
Here an example (inside store's constructor):

```
constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
me.callParent([Ext.apply({
                autoLoad: true,
                autoSync: true,
                model: 'Test.model.Country',
                proxy: {
                    type: 'rest',
                    api: {
                        create: 'country/create',
                        read: 'counrtry/list'
                        update: 'counrtry/update',
                        destroy: 'counrtry/destroy'
                    },
                    writer:{
                        writeAllFields : true
                    },
                    reader:{
                        root:'items',
                        totalProperty: 'rowCount'
                    }
                }
            }, cfg)]);
}
```

Extra note: For reading from server and load store automatically, just set store.autoLoad: true, and the corresponding **@RestController method** from server side. Take into account the **store.reader** params.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.For my usage I only need a one PUT request instead of the CRUD Api. Also my model is not of any type. The backend will distribute the informations where they belong. They for sure do not belong to one single model entity in the frontend. Your solution seems to be accurate and is tidied up. I will keep it in mind since it shows a good way how to handle the data.